# Filling a list with values in a range

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of dates like below :

```
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
NULL
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
NULL
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
NULL
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
```

This should be filled like this. 
that is to fill all dates that has similar neighbors up to 2 NULL values.

```
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
NULL
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-03-20 00:00:00.000
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
NULL
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
```

Here is what I build so far. Any idea is appreciated

```
DateTime? latestDate = null;

foreach (var date in dates)
{
    if (date == null)
    {
        latestDate = date;
    }
    else
    {
        date = latestDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify *similar neighbors up to 2 NULL values*?

Comment: For the following array `{ null, null, 1 }` will the result be  `{ 1, 1, 1 }` or `{ null, null, 1 }` ?

Comment: @DragandDrop it should be  `{ null, null, 1 }` since there is no left neighbor.

Comment: @RoadRunner  basically  if there is any null between 2 similar dates, it will be filled with that date.  and the number of in between nulls are restricted to 2

Comment: May you rules this case for me will `{ 1, null, null, 2 }` give `{ 1, null, null, 2 }` or `{ 1, 1, 1, 2 }`? And if you find the time tellm me if the case in the first paragraphe of my answer are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplification and to not deal with string parsing and date comparaison.
In order to have a clear [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), `DateTime` are now `int`.
[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/alXmPO)

#### Test case.

Base on the question I have the following test case:

```
//Input                           Expected Output
{ null, 1 },                    { null, 1 } 
{ null, null, 1 },              { null, null, 1 } 
{ null, null , null, 1 },       { null, null , null, 1 } 

{ 1, null, 1 },                 { 1, 1, 1 } 
{ 1, null, null, 1 },           { 1, 1, 1, 1 } 
{ 1, null, null, null, 1 },     { 1, null, null, null, 1 } 

{ 1, null, 2 },                 { 1, null, 2 } 
{ 1, null, null, 2 },           { 1, null, null, 2 } 
{ 1, null, null, null, 2 },     { 1, null, null, null, 2 }
```

#### The code.

Here we won't look for code optimisation, minimum variable assignation or keeping the last value we just read.
We stay close to the test case.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (i == 0) { continue; } //First elment? Skip.
    if (input[i] != null) { continue; }// Already have a value? Skip.

    // First and last elment are safe.
    int? closestValueLeft = input[i - 1];
    int? closestValueRight = input[i + 1];

    // ####  CASE 1 #### : Left and right have value. 
    if (closestValueLeft != null && closestValueRight != null)
    {
        if (closestValueLeft == closestValueRight)
        {// both are the same. 
            input[i] = closestValueLeft;
        }
    }

    // ####  CASE 2 #### : Left and right don't have value. 
    else if (closestValueLeft == null && closestValueRight == null)
    {// Left and right have no value, Skip.
        continue;
    }

    // ####  CASE 3 #### : We have to move a bit to find 
    else
    {// Either left or right have a value but not both. We are gona move one step after the null. 
        if (closestValueLeft != null)
        { // Left is not null move right. 
            if (i + 2 < input.Length)// Array out of bound protection
            {
                closestValueRight = input[i + 2];
            }
        }
        else
        {// Right is not null, move left. 
            if (i - 2 > 0)// Array out of bound protection
            {
                closestValueLeft = input[i - 2];
            }
        }

        if (closestValueLeft == closestValueRight)
        {
            input[i] = closestValueLeft;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make this neighbors up to 2 number configurable

Comment: Configurable? Like 1 or 2 or 4-99

Comment: In case 3 after the Letfnotnull and right not null. You can add a for loop looping from 2 to infinity. You keep the out of bound You just change 2 by new counter

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, this is the solution:

```
foreach (var date in dates.Select((date, index) => new { date, index }))
{
    if (date.index - 2 < 0) continue;

    if (dates[date.index - 2].HasValue && 
        dates[date.index - 2].Value == date.date && 
       !dates[date.index - 1].HasValue)
    {
        dates[date.index - 1] = date.date;
    }
    else if (dates[date.index - 3].HasValue &&
             dates[date.index - 3].Value == date.date &&
            !dates[date.index - 1].HasValue &&
            !dates[date.index - 2].HasValue)
    {
        dates[date.index - 1] = date.date;
        dates[date.index - 2] = date.date;
    }
}
```

@Drag and Drop  thx good idea

```
for (int index = 0; index < dates.Count(); index++)
{
    if (index - 2 < 0) continue;

    if (dates[index - 2].HasValue &&
        dates[index - 2].Value == dates[index] &&
       !dates[index - 1].HasValue)
    {
        dates[index - 1] = dates[index];
    }
    else if (index - 3 >= 0 &&
             dates[index - 3].HasValue &&
             dates[index - 3].Value == dates[index] &&
            !dates[index - 1].HasValue &&
            !dates[index - 2].HasValue)
    {
    dates[index - 1] = dates[index];
    dates[index - 2] = dates[index];
}
```

Comment: `if (date.index - 3 < 0)` Is not really intuitive too. And array with {1,null,1}. Will be ignored.

Comment: I edited your answers as `(date.index - 3 < 0)` will simply return a wrong result. And you corrected that in the second part. But a quick question: Your answer is right to the point and the algo is correct. But, Do you really find `( XYZ - 2 < 0)` more readable than `( XYZ < 2 )`. It's not a question about style, I just haven't found anyone that wrote it like that before.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this as not recreated the List of dates, but this (or something pretty close) should work

```
if (dates.Count > 2)
{
      int i = 0;
      do
      {
          if (dates[i] != null && dates[i + 1] == null && dates[i + 2] == null && (i + 3 >= dates.Count || dates[i + 3] != null))
          {
              dates[i + 1] = dates[i];
              dates[i + 2] = dates[i];
              i += 3;
          }
          else i++;
      } while (i < dates.Count - 3);
  }
```

EDIT:
I may have misunderstood the original requirement (see comment).  If so, this may be more suitable

```
        if (dates.Count > 2)
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                if (dates[i] != null && dates[i + 1] == null && dates[i + 2] == dates[i])
                {
                    dates[i + 1] = dates[i];
                    i += 2;
                }
                else if (dates[i] != null && dates[i + 1] == null && dates[i + 2] == null && (i+3<dates.Count && dates[i + 3] == dates[i]))
                {
                    dates[i + 1] = dates[i];
                    dates[i + 2] = dates[i];
                    i += 3;
                }
                else i++;
            } while (i < dates.Count - 3);
        }
```

Comment: Well {1, null, null, 2} will return {1, 1, 1, 2}. In Op exemple lines 3 , we have {1, null, 2} that stay that way. While this exemple work in your case,  and as  {1, null, null, 2}  is not in the give exemple we cannot say at 100% if it work or not. Gentleman way to say; in a case not documented I think it does not.

Comment: @DragandDrop true, but that's how I understood the requirement from the OP,  i.e. to replace two null values with previous date.  I this the requirement could be up to two null values between matching dates.  I've amended answer to include this.